# No output on login form

Tags: php, mysql

This is the login php script, I don't get no errors or echos so I have no idea what's going on. The "*'s" is me censoring that info. If you would like to see the live page it is [here](http://atsbusinessandgames.com/Login/).

```
<?php
printf("Client library version: %s\n", mysqli_get_client_info());

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
var_dump('test');
if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
    echo $username
    echo $password

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "atsbusin_atsbusin", "Andrew85") or die ("Failed to connect to DB");
mysql_select_db("atsbusin_users") or die ("failed to select DB");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows != 0)
        {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $dbusername = $row['username'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];
            }

                if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
                {
                    echo "Login Success!";
                    $_SESSION['username'] == $dbusername;
                } else {
                    echo "Incorrect password!";
                }

        } else {
            die("invalid username, check the spelling or register that name");
        }

}
    echo 'something'
?>
```

This is the final working code, thanks to all who helped! Now for me to switch over to mysqli and do the security measures suggested (have a  feeling I'll be back ☺ )

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "atsbusin_atsbusi", "Andrew85") or die ("Failed to connect to DB");
mysql_select_db("atsbusin_users") or die ("failed to select DB");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $dbusername = $row['username'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];

            }

            if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
            {
                echo "Login Success!";
                $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
            } else {
                echo "Incorrect password!";
            }
?>
```

Comment: By the way I set up a  sample user with the username of "test" and the password of "testpw" if that will help anyone at all.

Comment: **WARNING:** You're using a deprecated database API. Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). You have also given the ability for anyone to perform an SQL injection.

Comment: I suggest you two things:

- Ther's a huge SQL Injection. Read about [safety](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)
.
- mysql_* functions are deprecated. Consider switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

For what concerns your script, given that in case something goes wrong you have several error message, if you get no actions the script is probabily not entering your main if clause. Try to add an `echo 'something'` just after `if($username && $password)`

Comment: @Phate01 Did that and nothing got echoed out.

Comment: @carstorm: as I was expecting, replace your if with `if (!empty($username) && !empty($password))` to check whether they are empty

Comment: Still nothing, I'm half tempted into thinking php isn't working however it is at otehr parts of my site so I know that can't be it!

Comment: Im glad it's working man :) Good luck in the future

Comment: TY once the project is be done I'll be happy with the fruits of the labor, I got a database of data off to a  good start, just need to work on getting the  user database set up then work on the relational issues ☺. I have some work ahead of me ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this wont echo anything and not give you an error is **If the username exists and the password does not match** So it will go through:

```
if($numrows != 0){

}
```

Try to put a `var_dump('test');` in that IF statement and see if it does show something.

You also have no `;` after the

```
$username = $_POST['username']
$password = $_POST['password']
```

change it to:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Some extra notes:

1. you probably want a `else` around: `die("Do not leave username and/or password field blank");`
2. Dont use mysql it will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.
3. You're wide open to MYSQL injection

**EDIT:**

It also wouldn't show an error or echo **if you fill in the username and password and they both dont match**

Comment: I am not yet beefing up the code but know about sql injection.

I make sure they are not blank by using the html5 attribute required.

I will look into another framework, didn't realise it was being phased out.

Comment: @carstorm Did any of these points get you any further? Any errors you're getting now perhaps? Also read hd his answer

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.4.33. Also right now I'm just trying to get it to work and will do sha2 and salts and sanitising later. Still not getting any different output even after fixing the 2  syntax errors (adding the ";" and change the "$$" to "&&". I'm looking into the MySQLi now.

Comment: @carstorm how about the `var_dump('test');` and the else around the die?

Comment: Nothing, I think it may be that php itself isn't working. Edit: it is because I use php elsewhere on teh site and all of that stuff works.

Comment: @carstorm Update your question with the code you have now. So the one with the right changes.

Comment: @carstorm at the `echo $username` you forgot a `;` again. `$_SESSION['username'] == $dbusername;` should be `$_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;`

Comment: You shouldn't have updated your question as most points in all answers will not become irrelevant. If you wanted to update @Loko with your codebase, you should have used a pastebin service.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I've seen it on alot of questions though and it helps the OP to solve the question. We wouldn't proceed without the updated code.

Comment: In that case, OP should have updated their question with a seperate code block with their new code, or provided a pastebin link to you - or take it to chat to help debug. But I digress, and won't argue practices here. `:)` Please continue

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I agree for the sake of future visitors this is really confusing, but I dont think this question will help future visitors in his normal state anyway.

Comment: I changed some setting of the configs for php and with your above changes got it to output, however there still must be  a logic error because its saying invalid login when I put in correct values. This is the output "Client library version: 5.5.42 string(4) "test" testtestpwinvalid username, check the spelling or register that name"

Comment: @carstorm Invalid login? You mean incorrect password or invalid username, check the spelling or register that name?

Comment: updated with latest code, now I get the error "Incorrect password!" When I know I am using the correct one, copy/paste

Answer (score 1):

There are some php syntax errors in your script.

You have missed semicolons at below lines, update code and set display errors on to see if there is any other error

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some syntax and logical errors.

**1)** You're missing `;` when variable assigning.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

**2)** You're not using `&&` in your `if()` statement, but two `$`

```
if ($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
```

**3)** You're using a comparison (`==`) on your `$_SESSION` and not an assignment (`=`).

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
```

Notes

- Check the password matches the one in the database on the query itself (after you encrypt it)

  - With your current logic, it suggests you store your passwords in plain text. This is a **BIG NO-NO**.
- You're wide open to SQL injections

Comment: Wow the second point. I didn't even notice that and it's such a weird mistake by the OP.